# How to change App Center Secret key at runtime as I change environment in the react-native app

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I change my environment from testing to staging in the react native app at runtime & I want the crash logs to be stored in different paths in app center based on the environment I'm into. How can I manage to change the app center secret key whenever I change the environment in the app?

I tried different links but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Did you found a way to do it ?

Comment: @NourB No. We just carried over with the way it works and lighing everything in one place for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom pre-build script.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/

The content will be something like this:

```
APP_CENTER_CONFIG_ANDROID_PATH=**path to your appcenter-config.json**
APP_CENTER_CONFIG_IOS_PATH=**path to your appcenter config .plist**

if [ -n "$REACT_NATIVE_APPCENTER_SECRET" ]; then
    sed -i '' 's/"app_secret": "[^"]*"/"app_secret": "'$REACT_NATIVE_APPCENTER_SECRET'"/' $APP_CENTER_CONFIG_ANDROID_PATH
    echo "File APPCENTER CONFIG:"
    cat $APP_CENTER_CONFIG_ANDROID_PATH
fi

if [ -n "$REACT_NATIVE_APPCENTER_SECRET" ]; then
    plutil -replace AppSecret -string $REACT_NATIVE_APPCENTER_SECRET $APP_CENTER_CONFIG_IOS_PATH
    echo "File APPCENTER CONFIG:"
    cat $APP_CENTER_CONFIG_IOS_PATH
fi
```

Dont forget to declare the variables
**REACT_NATIVE_APPCENTER_SECRET** on your appcenter

and **APP_CENTER_CONFIG_ANDROID_PATH** and **APP_CENTER_CONFIG_IOS_PATH** on script file.